# Tree Traversal with 2 threads, printing node data simultaneously

Tags: multithreading, tree

We are given two threads which perform a pre-order traversal. We have to print data such that for the following example tree:

```
           1
        /     \
       2       3
      / \     / \
     4  NULL NULL NULL
    / \
 NULL NULL
```

...the output is: `1 1 2 2 4 4 3 3`

Here the first "thread1" should print one value, and then "thread2" should print a value.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Following is one of possible solution is there any other optimise solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

bool ready1 = false;
bool ready2 = false;
mutex m;
condition_variable cond;

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
 
    Node(int val)
    {
        data = val;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }
} Node;

void prod1(Node *root) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
        cond.wait(lock, [](){
            return ready1;
        });
        cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<root->data<<endl;
        ready2 = true;
        ready1 = false;
        lock.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();
        prod1(root->left);
        prod1(root->right);
    
}

void prod2(Node *root) {
        if (root == NULL) {
            return;
        }
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
        cond.wait(lock, [](){
            return ready2;
        });
        cout<<std::this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<root->data<<endl;
        ready1 = true;
        ready2 = false;
        lock.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();
        prod2(root->left);
        prod2(root->right);
    
}
 
int main()
{
    /*create root*/
    struct Node* root = new Node(1);
    root->left = new Node(2);
    root->right = new Node(3);
    root->left->left = new Node(4);
    /* 4 becomes left child of 2
               1
            /     \
           2       3
          / \     / \
         4  NULL NULL NULL
        / \
     NULL NULL
    */
    thread t1(prod1, root);
    thread t2(prod2, root);
     {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m);
        ready1 = true;
       // std::cout << "main() signals data ready for processing\n";
    }
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    //preorder(root);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *"is there any other optimise solution"*: the answer section should not be used for asking questions. If this was your main question, then edit your question and add this to it. Then at least your question will be a **question**, which currently is lacking.